# How to add sucesive spots in plotly (python) using slider?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly, slider

I am trying to make a plotly graph which could plot the evolution of a parameter's value along a period of time.

By now, what I've managed to get is plotting individual points. However, I'd like to keep the previos spots plotted while getting an increment on the slider.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
fig=px.scatter(df, x="$R[\Omega]$", y="$X[\Omega]$", title='$U_1/I_1$',animation_frame="t[seg]")
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus")
fig.show()
```

**Data**

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({"$R[\Omega]$":[-0.092034,-0.096416,-0.103026],
                         "$X[\Omega]$":[0.045707,0.047590,0.039953],
                         "t[seg]":[0.416244,0.417078,0.417912]})
```

Comment: Please add dummy data to your question to help us to reproduce your work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Replacing the 5th line with this one, you can test with some of the values: df2=pd.DataFrame({"$R[\Omega]$":[-0.092034,-0.096416,-0.103026],"$X[\Omega]$":[0.045707,0.047590,0.039953],"t[seg]":[0.416244,0.417078,0.417912]})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simulated data as I don't have access to your excel spreadsheet.  Named columns consistently with what your code implies
- need to make sure `layout` has axes ranges set for all data
- after building figure, for each frame update the data in traces such that it contains all values from previous frames as well.  (Note this assume that **t[seg]** is numeric)

### full code

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# df=pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
# generate data in structure implied by question
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "$R[\Omega]$": np.linspace(0, 100, 250),
        "$X[\Omega]$": np.sin(np.linspace(0, 50, 250)),
        "t[seg]": np.linspace(0, 100, 250) // 10,
    }
)
xcol = "$R[\Omega]$"
ycol = "$X[\Omega]$"
fcol = "t[seg]"
fig = px.scatter(
    df, x=xcol, y=ycol, title="$U_1/I_1$", animation_frame=fcol
)
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus")
# prepare axes to show all values
fig.update_layout(
    {
        ax: {
            "range": [
                df[col].min(),
                df[col].max(),
            ]
        }
        for ax,col in zip(["xaxis", "yaxis"], [xcol,ycol])
    }
)

# add data into each frame from all preceeding traces
for fr in fig.frames[1:]:
    df_ = df.loc[df[fcol].le(float(fr.name))]
    for t in fr.data:
        t.update(x=df_[xcol].values, y=df_[ycol].values)
    
fig
```

[image]

Comment: pls consider accepting if this solution meets your needs